# Will it work to use swig director to call a go function from C/C++ library built with MSVC in Windows

Tags: go, visual-c++, callback, swig

I am trying to use swig (4.1.1) to call a go function from C/C++ library built with MSVC (VS2015) in Windows. I used swig director feature do that. But the go function was never hit, and didn't report any error in C/C++ library, all C++ code before and after the callback runs fine.

When I built the same C/C++ library with TDM-GCC in Windows, it works fine, and the go function can be hit successfully.

I also tried the same code in Linux (C/C++ library was built with GCC), it also works fine.

I understand CGO doesn't support MSVC compiler, I am in full control of C/C++ library code and Go code, but I must use MSVC to built C/C++ library, is there any way to work around this callback issue in Windows?

Thanks,

Comment: Did anyone use swig to successfully call go function from c library in Windows?